# Passing parameters in a response.sendRedirect() - JSP

Tags: html, jsp, redirect, httprequest

I am new to Web Technologies. I am trying to do a simple program which ask the user to input a name, if valid the page redirects to another jsp file `"RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp"`, if invalid the page redirects to `"RedirectIfFailed.jsp"`. I am using the `response.sendRedirect()` method to do this.

The redirect is working fine. However, I wish to access the name the user inputs in the form from `RedirectIfSuccessful` and `RedirectIfFailed` files so that when a valid name is entered the user is presented with a : Welcome, nameEntered and when failed the message would be nameEntered was not valid. Please go back and try again.

I tried using `request.getParameter("name")` from  both files but it's returning a `null` value.. What can I do to access it?

This is the code I have: This is the `RedirectingPage.jsp`

```
 <%@ page 
    language="java" 
    import="java.util.regex.*"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<%  
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    final String NAME_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(NAME_PATTERN);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);

    if (matcher.matches() == true){
        response.sendRedirect("RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp");

    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("RedirectIfFailed.jsp");
    }

%>
```

This is the HTML file where I have the form: `FormSubmit.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Welcome </title>
    </head>

    <body BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">
        <p> <i> This program redirects to a page if the name entered is valid and to another one if name
            entered is invalid... This uses response.sendRedirect() </i> </p>

        <form action="RedirectingPage.jsp" method="post">
          <font size=6 face="Georgia"> <strong> Enter your name: </strong> </font> <input type="text" name="name"> <br> <br>
          <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the Successful page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> Successful Submit </title>
</head>

<body>

<font face="Georgia" size="6"> Hello, <% request.getParameter("name"); %> </font>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help and I was clear in my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A redirect consists in sending a response to the browser saying *"Please go to the following URL : RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp"*.

When it receives this response, the browser sends a new request to `RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp`, without any parameter. So getting the parameter `name` from `RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp` will return null.

If you want to have access to the name after the redirection, you need to send a redirect to `RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp?name=<the name the user entered>`

Comment: Oh ok I understand, so when the browser creates the new request, it would be without parameters. So if I use forward() method instead of sendRedirect() it would hold the parameter, right? Because the browser wouldn't be creating a new request? I didn't quite understand what the last line of code means though :/ Thanks for your answer JB :)

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. And indeed, a forward would not have this behavior. Note that it's good practice to redirect (and not forward) after a successful POST. This is [the post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). The last sentence means: you can redirect to a URL containing a request parameter. For example if you send a redirect to `RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp?name=John`, the browser will send a GET request to `RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp?name=John`, and the JSP will have access to the parameter `name`, which will have the value `John`

Comment: Yes I agree with you to use sendRedirect in this case.. I am trying to do this in RedirectPage however it's still showing null:

response.sendRedirect("RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp?name=enteredName");

where String name = request.getParameter("name");
and String enteredName = name;

Comment: In the url it is displaying name=enteredName and not name=John :/ I am encoding the URL also and getting the parameter normally. can't figure out what the problem is :/

Comment: It should of course be `response.sendRedirect("RedirectIfSuccessful.jsp?name=" + enteredName);` (and the enteredName should be URL encodeded as well in case it contains special characters)

Comment: Omg that was one noob mistake haha :( Sometimes I look at the harder things and don't look at the obvious which is in front of me! It works fine now :p Thanks a lot JB :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the name in another page, use session.

e.g. `session.setAttribute("name",name)` at the login page;

To retrieve the name, use `session.getAttribute("name")`. You can assign it to a variable like this:

```
<% String name=(string)session.getAttribute("name");%>
```

success!