# How to write response.sendRedirect() method with paramters in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, request-response

I have the following code in one of my JSP :

```
<c:redirect url="someFile.jsp">
    <c:param name="source" value="${param.source}" />
    <c:param name="target" value="${param.target}" />
    <c:param name="value" value="${param.value}" />
</c:redirect>
```

The requested JSP [ **someFile.jsp** ] access the parameters by the below way :

```
String source = request.getParameter("source");
String target = request.getParameter("target");
String value  = request.getParameter("value");
```

But instead of `<c:redirect url` I need to use `response.sendRedirect("someFile.jsp")` method.
But I am not sure how to use the above parameters along with the jsp file name in the sendRedirect method.

Can someone help me out how should I write my redirect method.Can we do something like this :

```
response.sendRedirect("someFile.jsp?source=" + source +  "?target=" +target + "?value=" +value);
```

**OR**

```
session.setAttribute("source",source)
session.setAttribute("target",target)
session.setAttribute("value",value)

response.sendRedirect("someFile.jsp")
```

Comment: I think that might explain why you can not achieve what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020288/7237884

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos :  response.sendRedirect("someFile.jsp?source=" + source +  "?target=" +target + "?value=" +value); Can we do like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it using [`response.sendRedirect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) because `response.sendRedirect` simply asks the browser to send a **new** request to the specified path which means the new request won't get any information from the old request.

You can use do it using [`RequestDispatcher#forward`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) which forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("someFile.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("someFile.jsp?source=" + source +  "?target=" +target + "?value=" +value);`

Can we do like this ?

Comment: @Som - No, not this way; but there is a workaround. You can put the values into the `session` object before the redirection and then retrieve them from the `session` object after the redirection.

Comment: like what i have given in OR part ?

Comment: @Som - Yes, like what you have added to your question after editing it.

Comment: yeah actually i am looking for a workaround..probably ur suggestion might work..let me test it...